# Calculating area of a function using Riemann's Sum

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

```
f[x_] := 2/(2x+2)
Limit[
    Sum[
        deltaX = 1/n;
        xk = 0 + k * deltaX; 
        f[xk]*deltaX, 
        {k, 1, n}
    ],
    n-> \[Infinity]
]
```

I have the following code however, It doesn't work. The error:
$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded

The function is defined on the interval [0, 1]

Comment: You don't have a base case for the recursion.  At some point, you have to stop and say, "good enough". Hopefully before you hit your stack limit.

Comment: But It's supposed to calculate a limit?

Comment: Never mind. I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked fine. Perhaps you had set variables in memory.

[image]